# How to convert xml files from folder and save to xls in different folder by VBscript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm running this script, but in Targetfolder nothing appears, no files. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you for your time!

```
Dim xlApp, xlWkb, SourceFolder, TargetFolder, file
Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const xlNormal = 1
SourceFolder = "c:\temp\XMLfiles"
TargetFolder = "c:\temp\XLSfiles"

'Hide Excel
xlApp.Visible = False

'Process each file in SourceFolder
For Each file In fs.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files
'Open file in SourceFolder
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file)
'Get Filename
BaseName = fs.getbasename(file)
'Concatenate full path. Extension will be automatically added by Excel
FullTargetPath = TargetFolder & "\" & BaseName
'Save as XLS file into TargetFolder
xlWkb.SaveAs FullTargetPath, xlNormal
'Close file
xlWkb.Close
Next

Set xlWkb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing

MsgBox "Finished. Have a nice day!"
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Try running Excel unhidden (`xlApp.Visible = True`) and see if you get an error.

Comment: Thanks, Code works fine, i just put the script into a text file with extension '.vbs' =)

Answer (score 0):

Put the script into a text file with extension '.vbs'